# Python - Search with two condition in two dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

The first is (df1):
[image]

The second is (df2):

[image]

My problem is to get the Internal Code - Variation from df1 in df2 by comparing VARIATION and MAIN PRODUCT CODE v2.

Example:
In DF2: When MAIN PRODUCT CODE v2 is TN1050 and VARIATION is _1PCS then it needs to get "UTB1050_1PCS". Where DF2 takes reference from DF1.

My output should be like this in df2:

[image]

I really appreciate your help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how="left", left_on=["VARIATION", "MAIN PRODUCT CODE v2"], right_on=["VARIATION", "MAIN PRODUCT CODE v2"])
```